# Lists as reference types in python

Tags: python, primes

Following is the piece of code that i wrote to calculate the nth prime number.
I initialize arr = [2,3,5]; and prime(arr,n) is supposed to modify arr to contain first n prime numbers. But arr does not reflect changes after prime(arr,n) is executed.
I read that lists are passed as reference types ,so what is the problem in the following code.
t denotes the number of test cases against which verification has to be done.

The program results in an error saying array index out of bound for arr.

```
import sys;
def prime (arr,n):
    while(len(arr)< n):
        num=arr[len(arr)-1]+1;prime=0;
        while(prime==0):
            prime = 1
            for val in arr:
                if(num%val==0):
                    prime=0;
                    break;
            if(prime == 1):
                print "hello";
                arr = arr + [num];print arr; print "--";
            else:
                num = num+1;


t=raw_input();
t=int(t);
arr=[2,3,5];
ans =[];
for v in range (0,t):
    n = raw_input();
    n = int(n);
    if(n<=len(arr)):
        ans = ans + [arr[n-1]];
    else:
        prime(arr,n);print arr;print"arr was printed"
        ans= ans + [arr[n-1]];
print ans;print 'ans ';
```

below is sample run of the above code

```
>>> 
1
4
hello
[2, 3, 5, 7]
--
[2, 3, 5]
arr was printed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pulkit\Desktop\Random\nth_prime.py", line 30, in <module>
    ans= ans + [arr[n-1]];
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you're indentation is off. Tip for proper indentation on SO: Use 4 spaces for each level of indentation, don't use TAB (`\t`).

Comment: Actually i copied the code from the python script so the \t also got copied. Will take care from  next time.

Comment: In python this arr[len(arr)-1] should be written like this arr[-1]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the line:

```
arr = arr + [num];
```

to

```
arr.append(num)
```

The new line actually changes the `arr` array. The original line didn't change it; it created a *new* variable called `arr` (it was a [rebinding operation instead of a mutating one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding#Rebinding_and_mutation))

Sample run after this change:

```
1
4
hello
[2, 3, 5, 7]
--
[2, 3, 5, 7]
arr was printed
[7]
ans
```

Comment: Explanation: `arr.append` actually changes the object pointed to by `arr`, while `arr = arr + [num]` creates a new list and reassigns the name `arr` to point to that new list, leaving the old one that got passed in unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that lists are reference types (whether they are passed as arguments or not). However, this has a specific well-defined meaning that is not identical to pass-by-reference. Something being a reference type simply means that it is always referred to via an abstract handle, instead of being copied (say, on variable assignment). It follows that mutable reference types can be mutated from more than one place - such as from another function.

In your specific case, use `arr.append(...)` instead of `arr = arr + [...]` (which is also incredibly more efficient in both time and space). The first mutated the list object, the latter creates a new list object and stores a reference to it in a local variable (instead of also updating the passed-in variable to refer to the new object, as it would be the case with pass-by-reference).